# is there a way determine the time spent by a user on each tab by using chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to implement a chrome extension which logs the time spent by a user on each tab.
I'm new to chrome extensions, if anybody has any idea please let me know.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "time spent". Anyway, you should start with the extensions overview in the documentation.

Comment: I am sure there is a way, though not exactly sure of the approach. But here are few extensions that you can check on how they capture the time spent. 

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/timestats/ejifodhjoeeenihgfpjijjmpomaphmah?hl=en

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-timer/ggnjbdfgigejghknieofeahaknkjafim?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be too difficult to implement, just a little bit of work.

1. [Log the current time](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) as soon as a [tab is opened](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onCreated)
2. When you need to calculate the time, you would just go to your storage and grab it out and subtract (currentTime - opededTime)
3. Additionally, you can also log the time when a tab is closed

You won't be able to log times for tabs that are already opened before your extension is installed.

```html
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.storage.local.set({tab.id : performance.now()});
});
```

Comment: To make your answer better, I'd add some code as opposed to just links. This makes the answer easier to use AND prevents the issue where links get changed / discontinued